# Is there any way I can rotate an armor stand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a pose emporium, and I'm making a crawling animation. Is there any way I can make an armor stand look like it's crawling? It needs to be a `/summon` command, too.

Answer (score 4):

[This video](http://youtu.be/LoLRLKyswTI) goes into explicit detail about how the armor stands work in minecraft, including how to `/summon`, edit with `/entitydata`, create custom poses and static artworks.

For your specific needs (look like it crawling) you can use commands to set the angle of the head (`Head`), arms (`LeftArm` and `RightArm`), body (`Body`), and legs (`LeftLeg` and `RightLeg`).

```
/entitydata @e[type=minecraft=ArmorStand]{Pose:{Head:[~f,~f,~f]}{RightArm:[~f,~f,~f]}{Body:[~f,~f,~f]}{LeftLeg:[~f,~f,~f]}}
```

Note: the `~f` relates to the 3 degrees of rotation - x, y, and z; from 180 to -180.

For example, if I wanted to tilt the head forward by 20 degrees, I would use the command

```
/entitydata @e[type=minecraft=ArmorStand]{Pose:{Head:[20f,0f,0f]}}
```

Comment: This tool should help posing armor stand. https://haselkern.github.io/Minecraft-ArmorStand/

Comment: I try that but it says this to me in red Usage entity dataTag I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is `/entitydata` command, that means that you change a entity. You must first place the armor stand. Or change the command to `/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Pose:{Head:[20f,0f,0f]}}`.